# .datepicker improper position on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

On my computer `.datepicker` shows correctly beneath the form:

[image]

But on my phone `.datepicker` overlaps the form:

[image]

```
<%= f.text_field :deadline, id: "six", class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Deadline (Optional)' %>
<script>
  $( "#six" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
</script>
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

**application.css**

```
*= require jquery-ui/datepicker
```

Maybe it has something to do with the z-index? I made the calendar width as small as I can on mobile without distorting it.